# R: Extract capital letters and special characters with strsplit and perl REGEX syntax

Tags: regex, r, text-mining, strsplit

How you would extract only the `/` with the following capital letters, and the whole `[[:punct:]]/$[[:punct:]]`.

```
text <- c("This/ART ,/$; Is/NN something something/else A/VAFIN faulty/ADV text/ADV which/ADJD i/PWS propose/ADV as/APPR Example/NE ./$. So/NE It/PTKNEG makes/ADJD no/VAFIN sense/ADV at/KOUS all/PDAT ,/$, it/APPR Has/ADJA Errors/NN  ,/$; and/APPR it/APPR is/CARD senseless/NN again/ART ./$:")

# HOW to?
textPOS <- strsplit(text,"(   )|(?<=[[:punct:]]/\\$[[:punct:]])", perl=TRUE)
#                          ^^^ 
#                         extract only the "/" with the following capital letters
#                         and the whole "[[:punct:]]/$[[:punct:]]"

# Expected RETURN:
> textPOS
[1] "/ART" ",/$;" "/NN" "/VAFIN" "/ADV" "/ADV" "/ADJD" "/PWS" "/ADV" "/APPR" "/NE" "./$." "/NE" "/PTKNEG" "/ADJD" "/VAFIN" "/ADV" "/KOUS" "/PDAT" ",/$," "/APPR" "/ADJA" "/NN" ",/$;" "/APPR" "/APPR" "/CARD" "/NN" "/ART" "./$:"
```

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `gregexpr` and `regmatches`:

```
regmatches(text, gregexpr('[[:punct:]]*/[[:alpha:][:punct:]]*', text))
# [[1]]
#  [1] "/ART"    "/NN"     "/VAFIN"  "/ADV"    "/ADV"    "/ADJD"   "/PWS"    "/ADV"    "/APPR"   "/NE"     "./$."    "/NE"    
# [13] "/PTKNEG" "/ADJD"   "/VAFIN"  "/ADV"    "/KOUS"   "/PDAT"   ",/$,"    "/APPR"   "/ADJA"   "/NN"     ",/$;"    "/APPR"  
# [25] "/APPR"   "/CARD"   "/NN"     "/ART"    "./$:"
```

In words the regex says: "find things that start with zero or more punctuation marks followed by a slash followed by one or more letters or punctuation.  If you want to include numbers switch to `[:alnum:]`.

---

Per comments, if you want only uppercase letters the regex would become:

```
regmatches(text, gregexpr('[[:punct:]]*/[[:upper:][:punct:]]*', text))
```

As @eddi suggests, `[A-Z]` and `[:upper:]` are roughly equivalent.  Again as @eddi suggests,  this regex will catch teh /LETTERS case as well as the /$punct case:

```
/[A-Z]+|[[:punct:]]/\\$[[:punct:]]
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. Nice :) Is it possible to add also the `/$` with any punctuation mark before and after?

Comment: don't know if OP wants that, but this also extracts punctuation in e.g. `"a,/AA"`

Comment: @eddi Good point. My complex `regex` chops are not up to the task of parsing all of that.  When I run into things like this, I often take it apart in a few steps rather than trying to build a single, massive `regex`.

Comment: @Justin: Thank you again! How it is possible to avoid the case when small letters follow the `/`. Would `[:upper:]` instead of `[:alpha:]` be proper (can it catch `$`)? The example before (changed) did not contained every relevant case described in text, sorry.

Comment: @alex just use `[A-Z]`

Comment: I think this works to satisfy OP's points `'/[A-Z]+|[[:punct:]]/\\$[[:punct:]]'`

Comment: @eddi Thank you! Do you mean `[[:punct:]]*/[[A-Z][:punct:]]*`. It only returns `character(0)`

Comment: @Justin Thank you very much! Wish you a nice day :)